# systemverilog - simpler way to avoid "range bounded by constant expr" issue

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I coded around that issue, but I think it's cumbersome; lacking the elegance I sought migrating from VHDL testbenches to vlog...

Have a look and LMK if there's a better way.
tmsg is a typedef struct. 
i,j are integers.
Declared a tmp to facilitate parsing a big vector into 16b slices.

```
 $display("----  Writing T1 message  -----");
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) // send most of the filename as hexascii
 begin
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j +=1) // bit assign the sliced vec *sigh*
        begin  
           tmp[j] = tmsg.fname[88-i*16-1-j];
        end    

    wr(`SEND_MSG_QUEUE + `SMQ_MSG_Q_REG, tmp, 0, 3);

    /* --- the original  "range slice issue" line *sigh again* ----
    wr(`SEND_MSG_QUEUE + `SMQ_MSG_Q_REG, 
                tmsg.fname[88-i*16-1:88-(i+1)*16], 0, 3);
    ------------------------------------------------------------- */
 end
```

Thanks in advance,
Jerry

Comment: played around a little more and found that the modified "+:" notation works as follows - and maintains compact notation.

Answer (score 0):

played around a little more and found that the modified "+:" notation works as follows - and maintains compact notation:

```
        wr(`SEND_MSG_QUEUE + `SMQ_MSG_Q_REG, 
                           tmsg.LBA[48-i*16-1 -:16], 0, 3);
```

So it's a downward vector from the start index, 16b long.

Not as straightfwd as VHDL, but not awful.